# Is there a rule why the correct spelling for "Marketing" is not " Marketting"?

Tags: consonants, doubled-consonants, vowel-length

I have always assumed that you doubled the consonant when the vowel preceding it is short.

`bet` and `betting` for example; Why is this different for `market` and `marketing`?

Comment: Because Webster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In a one-syllable verb ending in one consonant letter preceded by one vowel letter, double the final consonant letter (never double "w, x, y")."

It's the syllable that matters, not the length of a word, although most of the time these two are well related.

See more at: [Doubling the Final Consonant in a Verb](https://www.rong-chang.com/double_rule.htm)

Comment: Hello, Jason. As you might expect, with over 100 000 questions, many issues have already been covered. Entering 'double final consonant verb' in an in-house search gets you rapidly to a duplicate (of a duplicate), and a much fuller answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, so you are suggesting, a. rename hyperlink with plain English and b. it is a priority to use in-house search for duplicate questions alike. Correct?

Comment: I probably _should_ have mentioned (a1) (preferably) authoritative sources should be given in 'answers' (which you've done), (a2,3) correctly attributed (no) and linked (yes). // (b) You're new, so searches won't be as easy for you (and can be demanding even after quite a few years), but expect duplicates of many more obvious questions, and do a reasonable quick check. (c) Look at the length and quality of various answers at the previous threads (though not all of them satisfy the earlier requirements!) :)

Comment: Underlying this rule is that a second syllable is short anyway, so need not be marked, I suppose.

Comment: If a verb has two vowel letters before the final consonant letter, do not double the consonant letter.